# Implementing iOS graphics in Xcode?

Tags: ios

I've started to create an iPhone game. I have created a background in a design application and set the initial size to the iPhone 5 dimensions. I have imported the image as @2x The code I have implemented is the following,

```
    let backGround = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    backGround.position = CGPointZero
    backGround.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    backGround.blendMode = SKBlendMode.Replace
    self.size = CGSizeMake(backGround.size.width, backGround.size.height)
    self.addChild(backGround)
```

Running in the simulator, the background displays in the correct size for the iPhone 5/5s and the iPhone 6/6 Plus. However, with the iPhone 4s and all iPad devices, The top half and bottom half of my image are cut off. How do i go about fixing this ?

Comment: Have you provided the iPhone 4 and iPad versions of the image as well as the iPhone 5 version?

Comment: I have imported one image in the form of @2x. Should i be importing another size image into Xcode for the iPhone 4 and iPad?

Comment: Yes you need to simply all the relevant standard images (no suffix), high res images (@2x suffix), iPhone 5 images (-568h suffix) and your iPad versions of them (~ipad) and then the iPhone 6+ (@3x suffix)